# The 'q' in AJAX ("GET","some_page.php?q="+str,true)

Tags: ajax

In Native JS AJAX, I always see example from w3school with:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","some_page.php?q="+str,true);
```

with that 'q' behind `...php?q=...` then `$_GET['q']` at PHP page, I wonder is that a rule?
I did try replacing with 'p' and then $_GET['p'], it works too. Can I just use anything I want, say x, kk or kok...? Just to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`q` is a short form used for `query`. you can use anything there.

Many sites use `q`. For example Google.

But There is no such rule.

It is simply

```
url.php?key=value&key2=value&key3=value
```

They are keys and values together url query parameters

the `$_GET[key]` will get the value of the key.

There is also `$_POST` to handle post requests and more are there like `$_COOKIE`